How to handle phpstan undefined property when property is defined in propertyDefinitions?
I'm extending FieldItemBase and getting an "undefined property" error from phpstan.
Phpstan error:
  62     Access to an undefined property                                                              
         Drupal\field_encrypt\Plugin\Field\FieldType\EncryptedFieldStorageItem::$decrypted_value.     
          Learn more:                                                                               
            https://phpstan.org/blog/solving-phpstan-access-to-undefined-property                     

Code causing the error:
  public function encrypt(): void {
    // If the decrypted value is set encrypt it an overwrite.
    if ($this->decrypted_value !== NULL) {

Property is defined in propertyDefinitions():
class EncryptedFieldStorageItem extends FieldItemBase {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public static function propertyDefinitions(FieldStorageDefinitionInterface $field_definition): array {
    $properties = [];
    $properties['decrypted_value'] = DataDefinition::create('any')
      ->setLabel(new TranslatableMarkup('Decrypted data'))
      ->setComputed(TRUE)
      ->setClass('\Drupal\field_encrypt\EncryptedFieldComputedProperty');
    return $properties;
  }

What's the best practice for fixing this?  The property is defined in propertyDefinitions(), but phpstan doesn't see it.

PHPStan doesn’t understand how dynamic properties like those defined in propertyDefinitions() for a FieldItemBase class work.
PHPStan performs static analysis and does not execute the code, so it cannot see that decrypted_value is being dynamically created through propertyDefinitions().
From PHPStan Repo description:

PHPStan focuses on finding errors in your code without actually running it.

So there is two option:

Add PHPDoc annotation for the decrypted_value property in your EncryptedFieldStorageItem class (if you are using php >=8.1)
something like:

/**
 * Class EncryptedFieldStorageItem
 *
 * @property mixed $decrypted_value
 */
class EncryptedFieldStorageItem extends FieldItemBase { }

Here is an example from Drupal Dynamic Entity Reference module https://git.drupalcode.org/project/dynamic_entity_reference/-/blob/3.x/src/Plugin/Field/FieldType/DynamicEntityReferenceItem.php?ref_type=heads

Second option which is not ideal is to ignore the Error for This Line

public function encrypt(): void {
  // If the decrypted value is set, encrypt it and overwrite.
  /** @phpstan-ignore-next-line */
  if ($this->decrypted_value !== NULL) {
  }
}

